# Test a class and get output of that class to test the following class pytest

Tags: python, pytest

The script I want to test looks like this

```
class cnv_classifier:
  ´´´ A class that calls another classes´´´
   def __init__(self,user_input):

   # First class
   data_loaded = ReadFile(user_input)
   data_loaded = data.load()

   
   # Second class
   cnv_df = Filter(data_loaded)
   cnv_df = cnv_df_cvf_return_cnv()
```

Now, I want to test the inner classes. To test the first class I have done this

```
pytest.fixture()
def file_to_test():
   file_to_test = "path/file_name"
   return file_to_test 

def test_data_loaded(file_to_test):
   data_loaded = ReadFile(user_input)
   data_loaded = data.load()
   assert ...

# This works
```

Now, to test the second class, I need the outpput of the first class. How can I do this?

I have tried introducing a `return`, and call the function like this

```
def test_data_loaded(file_to_test):
   data_loaded = ReadFile(user_input)
   data_loaded = data.load()
   assert ...
   return 

# Call the function
test_data_loaded = test_data_loaded(file_to_test)

# Test the second class using the output of the first class
def test_filter():
   cnv_df = Filter(data_loaded)
   cnv_df = cnv_df_cvf_return_cnv()
   assert ...
```

This does not work, when I run pytest, it says `data_loaded is not found`

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. " I need the outpput of the first class" What does this mean? Are you talking about an *instance of* that class? Or perhaps the result of *calling a method* on that instance? (if so, which method?) Or just what?

Comment: Does test_filter() know what data_loaded is? is it global?

Comment: Thanks, I need the results of data loaded. It is a data frame (pandas), the first class import a file and created the data frame, the second class does a filtering process. In my application, there 10 classes called, each one takes the output of the previous one. To test all of them I need to link the classes as I do in my application. Is this approach correct?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think that when you run pytest, you only run the functions that start by test. You cannot call a method to be used for the following function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess that this way to do test is not corret. Or maybe how I have develop my main.py. I cannot find a way to test the second and posterior classes because each one take the argument generated by the previous class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you're trying to do in the end, and is perfectly acceptable. But the solution is a bit different.

To run a test inside another running test you should add all fixtures to the latter. In your case the code would look like this:

```py
def test_data_loaded(file_to_test):
   data_loaded = ReadFile(user_input)
   data_loaded = data.load()
   assert ...
   return data_loaded                             # <- Here

# Test the second class using the output of the first class
def test_filter(file_to_test):
   data_loaded = test_data_loaded(file_to_test)   # <- Here
   cnv_df = Filter(data_loaded)
   cnv_df = cnv_df_cvf_return_cnv()
   assert ...
```

Comment: I think that this is what tere is expecting. Let see what she think. I was wondering, she mention that there are 10 classes, if one want to test for example the number 8, in that case, do you have to call in that test the previous 7 classes?

Comment: @ManoloDominguezBecerra, let me know if this solves the problem when possible.